# Tabulator: Top and button calc not shifting position when a column is toggled. How to toggle column and refresh table without losing scroll position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabulator

My goal is to be able to toggle the visibity of toggles and keep the same formatting. Currently my solution to use a filter does this but loses the current scroll position of the tabulator. This is unaccepatable.

```js
$("#toggleNotes").change(function () {
    // Toggles the visibility of the Notes column.
    $("#allocations-table").tabulator("toggleColumn", "Notes");
    $("#allocations-table").tabulator("setFilter", "AllocationId", ">", -1);
});
```

Not using the filter results in the top and bottom calc not shifting to accomadate the new column. Is it possible to shift the top and bottom calc? Is there a way to recalculate column top and bottom calc without reseting the table each time?

I am using tabulator 3.5 and I am unable to upgrade to the latest version.

PS: Thanks for making the tabulator free.

Answer (score 0):

Even performance changed on v4.9 but some problems remain or produced.The `bottom/top calc` have problem even on version 4.9 when it comes to horizontal scroll.
Also there is problems with `RTL languages`. I have attached a sample image of sample table generated with `Tabulator 4.9`.
For Example if we active Frozen Column and same time set direction to RTL, the frozen row floating to the left while it should be fixed on the right side of table.
I have fixed soring carret position on my custom css easily,but others are remained yet.
[image]

These are only some problems on first hours of working with Tabulator new version.
[image: Another Example on official website]

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Tabulator.  If you scroll, it causes a redraw which moves the bottom or top calc row to the correct position.  You can force it by shifting the scroll position.

```
cell.getElement().closest('.tabulator-tableHolder').scrollLeft += 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to upgrade to a newer version of Tabulator to overcome those limitations. version 4.6 is the current version

Tabulator 4 does come with a [jQuery Wrapper](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/jquery) so you can continue using it just as before. and the docs have a step by step [Upgrade Guide](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/upgrade) to take you through making the changes.

I have upgraded sites with hundreds of tables and it has taken between a few minutes and a few hours depending on complexity of the tables

Comment: Just to clarify. Does version 4.6 shift the top and bottom calc when a new column is added and include a way to recalculate column top and bottom calc without reseting the table each time? If it does I will try and upgrade again.

Comment: Yes it does, there have been significant upgrades to every part of the table in the 4.x releases